# How was the speed of sound first measured? How did this impact the future of science?

Tags: acoustics, velocity

This is for a project in math! Feel free to use as much or as little detail needed to answer the question properly.

Comment: I recommend moving this question to the [history of science and mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions) stackexchange

Answer (score 3):

Isaac Newton was the first: he stood at one end of  the cloisters below the Wren Library in Trinity College. [He clapped rhythmically](https://mountainmystery.com/2015/08/13/newton-and-the-speed-of-sound/) so that each clap coincided with the echo of the preceeding clap from the other end. He  counted claps per minute and,  knowing the length of the cloisters, he determined  $c_{\rm sound}$.  He compared his  determination  with his theory that    $c^2= P/\rho$. His measurement was accurate enough that it  did *not agree* with his theory ---  so he cooked up a falacious theory about gaps between the air particles to explain the error.  He did not know that in adiabatic compression it is $PV^\gamma$ that is constant (and not $PV=nRT$) and this makes  $c^2 = \gamma P/\rho$ with $\gamma= C_P/C_V\approx 5/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Among the search results for measurement of speed of sound was a 1964 article titled [Laplace and the speed of sound](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Epowers/ame.20231/finn1964.pdf).

quoting from that article:

> Mersenne also used a gun, comparing the time of travel of the flash
> and the report [...] By 1660 the Florentine Academy had made careful
> measurements using a gun at a distance of about a mile.

I don't think measurement of the speed of sound stands out as impacting the development of physics one way or the other.

Let me describe a contrast to that:
There is the expression 'Experimentum crucis'. In the book 'Opticks' Newton describes his investigations into the nature of light. He describes that he did the separation of light into colors with a prism, at the time this was known to others. In addition, Newton described that he had created a setup with a second prism that effectively reassembled the light. Newton described that the setup reassembled light such that he had observed a white appearance again.

Just to be clear: in his own work Newton was extraordinarily meticulous and from his notebooks it is clear he always had many setups, to eliminate other possible explanations.

In the book 'Opticks' the experiment is described as a single experiment. If the colors can be reassembled to white light, then the white daylight itself must already consist of all colors. This experiment, Newton asserted, was an *Experimentum crucis*, necessitating a radical change of view.